# how to resolve Pyspark dataframes query error keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I am having two dataframes named tweetsDF and HashtagsDF. tweet_status_id of both the dataframes are equal and I want to retrieve hashtags count for a single tweet. This is the query I am using which inturns throws

```
ERROR : SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

tweet_hashtags_count_DF = tweetsDF.join(HashtagsDF,sum('tweetsDF.*'),tweetsDF.tweet_status_id == HashtagsDF.tweet_status_id & tweetsDF.tweet_status_id='636984052600274944').show()
```

Where I am wrong in the query ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `tweetsDF.tweet_status_id == '636984052600274944'` (`==` instead of `=`).

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
 I am getting new error which is unsupported operand type error. But now where in the query I have used '+'. Could you help me out with this ? @andrew

Comment: That's likely coming from `sum()`.  Check that everything in `tweetsDF` is a numeric data type.  (If you're still running into issues, open up a separate post.)

Comment: yeah andrew that error is from sum() function. tweetsDF is a combination of both strings and integers.